# Extending laravel 5.2 authentication

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-5

I am trying to connect Laravel to an external database for the authentication, though I am not sure how to go about it.

How would I go about extending Laravels authentication to allow for a custom login method?

The database is `auth` and it uses `username` or `email` to login with, the password hash is sha512.

What would be the best way?

Answer (score 3):

**Different database:**

I would say that the best way to do so is to define a separate connection for the specific model.

So, in your `database.php` config, add another connection (let's name it `mysql_auth`).

To use it in a model, you need to add this as a variable in the class:

```
protected $connection = 'mysql_auth';
```

Now, by default the model queries will do queries to that exact connection.

*Just as a note*, to build migrations, use `Schema::connection('mysql_auth')->create(...)`.

**Different hashing method:**

*Original:* 
To use different hashing functionality, you need to, basically, use a different class as a Hash class.

By default, hashing, as defined in providers, is done here: `Illuminate\Hashing\HashServiceProvider::class`. To change it, you'll have to create a separate, different class as a provider and change this line:

```
$this->app->singleton('hash', function () {
    return new BcryptHasher;
});
```

Now, this will then link to **your** hashing class (that will implement `HasherContract` interface) that will do the sha512 (or whatever else) hashing.

All in all, check out `Illuminate\Hashing\HashServiceProvider`, how it registers the hashing methods and `Illuminate\Hashing\BcryptHasher` for the methods that you need to implement to implement your hashing.

*Update:*

Comment out `Illuminate\Hashing\HashServiceProvider::class` in providers and add something like `\App\Providers\NewHashServiceProvider::class`. Now, we create a new provider(`app/Providers`). This should work:

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class NewHashServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Indicates if loading of the provider is deferred.
     *
     * @var bool
     */
    protected $defer = true;

    /**
     * Register the service provider.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        $this->app->singleton('hash', function () {
            return new \App\ShaHasher;
        });
    }

    /**
     * Get the services provided by the provider.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function provides()
    {
        return ['hash'];
    }
}
```

This actually returns **our** hasher, that we will create in a moment.

To implement `ShaHasher`, create a class that implements `HasherContract` (just like `BcryptHasher` does):

```
<?php

namespace App;

use RuntimeException;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Hashing\Hasher as HasherContract;

class ShaHasher implements HasherContract
{
    /**
     * Hash the given value.
     *
     * @param  string  $value
     * @param  array   $options
     * @return string
     *
     * @throws \RuntimeException
     */
    public function make($value, array $options = [])
    {
        return hash('sha512',$value);
    }

    /**
     * Check the given plain value against a hash.
     *
     * @param  string  $value
     * @param  string  $hashedValue
     * @param  array   $options
     * @return bool
     */
    public function check($value, $hashedValue, array $options = [])
    {
        if (strlen($hashedValue) === 0) {
            return false;
        }

        return hash('sha512',$value) == $hashedValue
    }

    /**
     * Check if the given hash has been hashed using the given options.
     *
     * @param  string  $hashedValue
     * @param  array   $options
     * @return bool
     */
    public function needsRehash($hashedValue, array $options = [])
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: That solves 1 problem, however the password is hashed differently than the laravel default, I must admit though the connection in the model is a pretty nifty feature

Comment: I've added more info on the hashing part of the question.

Comment: The cleanest method is using the `HashServiceProvider` as @Andrius mentioned. Good idea.

Comment: Can't seem to get the connection or table to read from the User model it just defaults

Comment: But you specified the second connection in your database.php and added ` protected $connection = '<NEW CONNECTION NAME>';` in your model?

Answer (score 0):

The new implementation for Sha512 would then probably be something like:

```php
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Hashing\Hasher;

class Sha512Hasher implements Hasher
{
    public function make($value, array $options = [])
    {

    }

    public function check($value, $hashedValue, array $options = [])
    {

    }

    public function needsRehash($hashedValue, array $options = [])
    {

    }
}
```

So you basically utilizing a [ServiceContract](https://laravel.com/docs/master/contracts) `Illuminate\Contracts\Hashing\Hasher`

To bind this use a [ServiceProvider](https://laravel.com/docs/master/providers):

```php
class Sha512ServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Register bindings in the container.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        $this->app->singleton('hash', function () { 
        return new App\Sha512Hasher; 
    });

    }
}
```